# Testing for equality with Doubles

Tags: java, null, compare, double, equals

In Java, the upper case Double can be null.

However if I have Doubles `a` and `b` and I do this:

```
if (a.equals(b))
```

it crashes if one of them is null. Is there a better way to compare them?

Comment: `Objects.equals(a, b)`.

Comment: "it crashes if one of them is null" Specifically, it crashes if `a` is null. Doesn't matter about `b`.

Comment: @AndyTurner `Objects.equals` since Java 7. Otherwise good old `null` checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way in Java 7+ is:

```
Objects.equals(a, b)
```

If you are using an earlier version of Java, you can use the conditional operator:

```
(a != null) ? a.equals(b) : (b == null)
```

Comment: Reading that last statement out loud for my own clarity: For `a.equals(b)` to work, `a` has to not be null (since there's no such thing as `null.equals(b)`). But if `a` IS null, then we simply check if `b` is null as well.

Comment: @KaliMa that is correct. The `(b == null)` could be written as `(a == b)`, alternatively, but I think that's more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct and sadly you have to add additional null-checks.
So you either have to write

```
if ((a != null && a.equals(b)) || (a == null && b == null))
```

or your code must not accept `null` values.

Comment: This isn't correct. You need `a != null && a.equals(b)`.

Answer (score 0):

A short way could be:

```
boolean c = (a != null && b != null) ? a.equals(b) : false;
if (c){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
if (null != a && null != b && a.compareTo(b) == 0) {
    // whatever goes here
}
```

Comment: What if a and b are null?

Comment: @KaliMa then it would be false which logically seems right to me since nulls typically wouldn't be considered to be equal. If you need the code to execute on equal values or when both are null then you could just add that as an or condition to the Boolean expression

Comment: Objects.compare(null, null) appears to be true, however; which is also the behavior I'd expect honestly

Comment: @KaliMa that works if both are null. If only 1 is null it'll give an NPE as well